# Get pixel value GDAL in C

Tags: gdal, c

I have the following code that works well to print out the individual values of pixels on a image (first band), using C-GDAL.

```
#include "gdal/gdal.h"
#include "gdal/cpl_conv.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
int main()
{

    // to store execution time of code 
    double time_spent = 0.0;
    clock_t begin = clock();

    GDALDatasetH raster;
    GDALAllRegister();
    raster = GDALOpen( "/home/roger/Documents/98_GDAL_C++_snippets/data/selected_files_l2a/S2A_MSIL2A_20180408T155531_N0206_R011_T17PLK_20180408T204658.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A014594_20180408T155557/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20180408T155531_B02_10m.tif", GA_ReadOnly);
    if(raster==NULL)
    {
    printf("Invalid Raster Dataset");
    }
    else
    {
    GDALRasterBandH raster_band;
    int XSize, YSize;

    raster_band = GDALGetRasterBand( raster, 1);
    GDALGetBlockSize( raster_band, &XSize, &YSize);
    //int *pafScan;
    int nXSize = GDALGetRasterBandXSize (raster_band);
    int nYSize = GDALGetRasterBandYSize (raster_band);
    //int line = CPLMalloc(sizeof(int) * nXSize * 1);
    float *line;
    line = (float *) CPLMalloc(sizeof(float)*nXSize);
    int row, col;
    int value;

    // looping through the pixels of this line;
    for (row = 0; row < nYSize; row++) {
        GDALRasterIO(raster_band, GF_Read,0, row, nXSize,1, line, nXSize, 1, GDT_Float32, 0, 0);
        // this is where you'd do your processing on the pixel 
        for(col=0;col<nXSize; col++){
            value = line[col];
            printf("%d\n", value);

        }


        }

        CPLFree(line);

    }
    clock_t end = clock();
    time_spent += (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Time elapsed is %f minutes\n", time_spent/60);

    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to only get the first pixel value(or a specific value), specifying the row and col coordinates in C?